# Trimming trailing zeros WITHOUT casting to float

Tags: php, regex

Let's try again but a bit more explicitly.

I am printing numbers to the screen and want to make them more friendly to users by stripping off trailing zeros after the decimal point. I have tried casting to a float but this solution is not a good fit as I handle numbers like 0.00000001 which come out along the lines of 0.1-e7 sort of thing which is unfriendly to end users.

I need a solution where number like the following...

```
12.02000000
12.00000000
0.00000001
```

...can be printed to the screen like...

```
12.02
12
0.00000001
```

Using rtim kills numbers like 10000. number_format needs to know the number of decimal places which may be from 0 to 8. Casting to float does not work. I'm sure that there is some regex for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the regex solution as you want:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?>\.0+$|(\.\d*[^0])0+$)/', '$1', $numstr);
```

**Testing:**

```
echo preg_replace('/(?>\.0+$|(\.\d*[^0])0+$)/', '$1', '12.02000000') . "\n";
echo preg_replace('/(?>\.0+$|(\.\d*[^0])0+$)/', '$1', '12.00000000') . "\n";
echo preg_replace('/(?>\.0+$|(\.\d*[^0])0+$)/', '$1', '0.0000000100000000') . "\n";
echo preg_replace('/(?>\.0+$|(\.\d*[^0])0+$)/', '$1', '100000000') . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
12.02
12
0.00000001
100000000
```

Comment: That is most excellent, thank you so much for taking the time on this.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler solution:

```
preg_replace("/(\.0*[^0]+)0*|\.0*/", '\1', $number)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search for internet i found something that could be useful:

```
function floattostr( $val )
{
    preg_match( "#^([\+\-]|)([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]*?)|)(0*)$#", trim($val), $o );
    return $o[1].sprintf('%d',$o[2]).($o[3]!='.'?$o[3]:'');
}
```

This will give you the output you need i guess

I found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php#106367)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex way to do it:

```
if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
    $number = rtrim($number, '.0');
}
```

Ternary operator style:

```
$number = strpos($number, '.') !== false ? rtrim($number, '.0') : $number;
```